# Connection to Amazon EC2 instance and RDS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm having some problems with the integration of my android app, Amazon EC2 and Amazon RDS system. Yesterday I create my ec2 instance, deployed my webservice, set up de security groups, and I did the same thing to my RDS system. Everything was working very well.

Today I can't retrieve any information from my RDS, nothing returns to my app. Although, I can connect to both systems through SSH, but neither from a navigator nor from my phone.

There are another configuration I should do to be capable to access all the time my systems from my app?

Comment: Did you happen to stop the EC2 instance since yesterday?

Comment: No David, I didn't do anything, I've just went to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out my mistake, It's was really missing some configuration to me to do. I needed to configure my tomcat service to launch automatically. Here is a link that can help everyone to configure their tomcat 7: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/amazon-free-usage-tier-installing-tomcat-7-on-an-ec2-linux-instance.html